# VLC surround to stereo problem

Tags: audio, vlc

I noticed a problem with certain video files where speech volume component is just too low. I googled a bit and it seems that the problem is that it tries to [play surround sound on stereo](http://www.codecguide.com/faq_playback_issues.htm#item16) speakers and it fails to blend everything in as it should. If I play the same video in mplayer, everything is normal.

Does anyone else have the same problem? Anyone know how to fix this?
I tried changing the output module in vlc audio settings, but the problem would remain no matter what I chose. Thanks.

Version of VLC that I am using is 1.1.12 on Arch-Linux (KDE 4.7.2).
If you any additional info is needed, I will provide it.

Comment: Downmixing/Adjust from 5.1 to 'true' 2.1 https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=133053

Surround sound in Linux:
http://www.halfgaar.net/surround-sound-in-linux

Answer (score 1):

**Downmixing/Adjust from 5.1 to 'true' 2.1**

I use ALSA and Pulse Audio on my Arch Linux machine.

You want to control how downmixing to 2.0 is done, so you're going to define a custom sound device in `/etc/asound.conf`

You can use this output configuration:

(add the custom function to the file `/etc/asound.conf`)

```
pcm.51to20
{
  type route
  slave.pcm surround51
  slave.channels 6

  # Front and rear, at 33% of original signal strength
  ttable.0.0 0.33
  ttable.1.1 0.33
  ttable.2.0 0.33
  ttable.3.1 0.33

  # Center channel routing (routed to front-left and front-right),
  # 6dB gaindrop (gain half of main channels) per channel
  ttable.4.0 0.16
  ttable.4.1 0.16

  # LFE channel routing (routed to front-left and front-right),
  # 6dB gaindrop (gain half of main channels) per channel
  ttable.5.0 0.16
  ttable.5.1 0.16
}
```

**Then in VLC**

Go to the audio preferences

Tools -> Preferences -> Audio

Set `Outputmodel` to `Alsa audio output`

and

Set `Device` to `Default ALSA Output (currently PulseAudio Sound Server)`

Save and restart VLC

Comment: This does not seem to work for me. Not even when testing it with aplay with some 5.1 file: `aplay -D 51to20 file.wav`. Why would this new audio device become default just from adding it? Btw. the [source](http://www.halfgaar.net/surround-sound-in-linux) of the config should be cited here too.